# submit search on enter key (not text-edit)

Tags: aviarc

Is there an event i can use to find out if a user has pressed the enter key while on a screen?

I want to submit search paramters from wherever the user is on the screen when they hit enter.

I realise i can do this if the focus is on a text-edit but what about a select-list, check-box etc.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Hi Tim. There is no default event which you can listen to for that particular use case. There is a hack you can use to achieve the results, but before I suggest it can you confirm whether you want the search to be run whenever user hits Enter key on the screen or only when focus it on some of the screen widgets?

Comment: Hi Vlad, i think only when they are on specified screen widgets. There are other things going on in the screen for which they may hit the enter key which shouldn't trigger the data refresh. i should also mention that the functionality is not a must have so if it's too complicated then i will leave it off.

Comment: Hi Tim. Yes, that could be a bit more involving. Would either require update of the relevant widgets to fire the event when they are in focus and Enter key is pressed or alternatively writing a new widget which will add a event to the specified widget list.

Comment: OK, don't worry about it, maybe it's something to note for a future release.